# SSRS 2016 custom ToolBar

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2016

I have a ssrs report

I want to remove few buttons like: "word", "powerPoint" from the toolBar,

Those buttons are under the "save button".

How Can I to do this?

Comment: where are you viewing your report? browser or somewhere else. could you post screenshot of your report where you actually view it

Comment: browser, chrome

Comment: as far as i know this is not possible unless you use JavaScript or something. But not from SSRS side.
But maybe someone else with more experience could provide some idea

Comment: At least I change few params at the reportsServer config file and it works, but I dont like it